# Scala: case class inheritance from traits with a typeless, parameterless abstract method

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, abstract-methods

For this example, assume the `spark: SparkSession` object is in scope. I plan on using InputSource with `pureconfig` to easily parse different config setups: table or file path in this MWE and return the dataframe. `loadDF` doesn't need to take any parameters since everything needed will be available from the case class.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

object InputSource {

  sealed trait InputType {

    def loadDF: DataFrame
  }

  case class TableSource(tableName: String, filter: String) extends InputType {

    def loadDF: DataFrame = {

      spark.table(tableName).where(filter)
    }
  }

  case class FileSource(filePath: String, format: String, filter: String) extends InputType {

    def loadDF: DataFrame = {

      spark.read.format(format).load(filePath).where(filter)
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked many blog posts, the scala tutorial and doc on polymorphism, traits, abstract methods and classes, and many SO posts. However, I cannot figure this one out.

> error: trait cannot redefine final method from class AnyRef
> def loadDF: DataFrame

I have encountered this before when the abstract method needed to define parameter type and that was solvable with

```
sealed trait DeequChecks {

    def configConstraint[C <: Check](check: C): CheckWithLastConstraintFilterable
}
```

Comment: Works fine both on my machine and [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gnNRRODcTtuqZ7yEugethg).

Comment: @HTNW hmm, that is perplexing. I am using Scala 2.11.12 and Spark 2.3.x what are you on?

Comment: Spark 3.0.1 and Scala 2.12.2, I think. Setting [Scastie to your versions](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1t6QYvmqRPe3plpLN0y8gA) also works fine. The error message you're getting is also *incredibly* weird... Are you sure that's scalac speaking and not some IDE code "intelligence" or whatever?

Comment: @HTNW I was testing it on IntelliJ. Sorry for the late response. I will try on Ammonite and see how that fairs. I was getting and even weirder error on Spark. I through it on the cluster to see what would happen there as well.